How do I play a simple beep sound, CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement package doesn't install
I need to play a simple beep sound.
After a lot of research this seems to be one of the best and easiest ways.
Accepted answer here.
how to play an audio file - .NET MAUI
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?tabs=windows
I created a new project and complied it.
But when I try to add the reference to
CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement (version 4.10)
it doesn't install.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement
The add reference finds it and acts like it installs it.
The output windows shows this.
Restoring packages for C:\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp.csproj...
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/vulnerabilities/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-vulnerabilities/2024.08.29.05.32.17/vulnerability.base.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-vulnerabilities/2024.08.29.05.32.17/2024.09.04.05.32.39/vulnerability.update.json
NU1605: Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Maui.Controls from 8.0.71 to 8.0.61. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 TestApp -> CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement 4.1.0 -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls (>= 8.0.71) 
 TestApp -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls (>= 8.0.61)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'TestApp'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.3859624
========== Finished ==========

I guess this is the problem. "Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version."
I found this "NuGet Warning NU1605" but still have no idea what to do to resolve this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605
How do I get this package to install or is there a better way to play a simple beep sound?

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var instance = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
    Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
    Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(instance.ApplicationContext, uri);
    rt.Play();
}

Also refer the media element document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?tabs=android

What is the correct using statement for this code? On compile I get "The name 'RingtoneManager' does not exist in the current context" and researching https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.ringtonemanager?view=net-android-34.0 says Namespace:  "Android.Media" and then adding using Android.Media; Gives the type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found??

have you tried this way? https://putridparrot.com/blog/plugin-maui-audio-plays-sound-even-if-android-device-is-set-to-vibrate/

Compile gives The name '_deviceAudioService' does not exist in the current context

I got it working using this plugin https://github.com/jfversluis/Plugin.Maui.Audio it is super simple var audioPlayer = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(TheSound)); audioPlayer.Play();  Researching your last answer led me to this. Thanks!

Good to see.. Appreciated for shared your solution
